# Netezza SQL scan function

Tags: sql, netezza

The issue is I have a table with an identifier column that is - seperated 
(example of a column value could be: TOM-XYZ12356-DIM34345-TE123456 
or
TOM-XYZR3455667AB-RXB75855-RYB434553)

My main focus is to try and extract that 2nd part of the identifier. In the above examples it would be (XYZ12356 and XYZR3455667AB). I tried something simple below but keep getting the error "Attribute '-' not found"

```
SELECT substr(identifier,1,Charindex("-",identifier) -1)
FROM TableA
```

Perhaps i am not specifying the start point correctly or maybe I am not using the right function. Can i use some ther function other than Charindex?

Comment: You probably need single quotes instead of double: `SELECT substr(identifier,1,Charindex('-',identifier) -1)`

Comment: Hey dnoeth, thanks for your quick response, i tried that just now after you suggested it and now i get the error "ERROR [42S02] ERROR:  Function 'CHARINDEX(UNKNOWN, VARCHAR)' does not exist"

Comment: I also tried Position function and i get the same error

Comment: Notes seems to support only Standard SQL POSITION and SUBSTRING: `substring(identifier from 1 for position('-' in identifier) -1)`. And now good luck with nested functions for the 2nd or 3rd or 4th part :-)

Comment: Thanks dnoeth, this got it partly working atleast now i get no function errors :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUBSTR and INSTR to get the results you want.

```
select * from tableA;
              COL1
--------------------------------
 TOM-XYZ12356-DIM34345-TE123456
(1 row)
```

SUBSTR works as you would expect (although it seems your parameters are out of order) and you can use INSTR to provide the start character after the first '-', and then calculate the SUBSTR length by substracting the position of the first '-' from the position of the second '-'.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(col1, instr(col1,'-',1,1)+1 , instr(col1,'-',1,2) - instr(col1,'-',1,1) -1 )
FROM tableA;

  SUBSTR
----------
 XYZ12356
(1 row)
```

Check the syntax for [SUBSTR and INSTR here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_ntz_sql_extns_char_funcs.html).

Comment: Thanks Scott, this worked for me perfectly. I will cross check my results with the full string just to make sure since in some instances the second part of the identifier can be longer or shorter but on a top 10 retrieve, it looks good. Thanks again for this, i will give your answer a green check and a +1

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to only select the second part of the identifier will this work?

```
select substr(('TOM - XYZ12356 - DIM34345 - TE123456'), 6, 9)
```

The result is just the second part:
 'XYZ12356'

Comment: Hey Uriel, unfortunately the 2nd part is varying in length, so i cannot specify 9 as a fixed #, it could be 11 characters in length and it could be 14 characters in some other instances. Thanks for the suggestion though